# How do I map an Observable using a function that maps it to an object where the values are observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Let's say I have a function that looks like this:

```
const mapObservableToObject = o$ => ({
  counter: o$.pipe(
    pluck('values', 'counter')
  )
  username: o$.pipe(
    pluck('user', 'username'),
    map(sanitizeUsername)
  )
  input: unrelatedObservable$.pipe(
    pluck('target', 'value'),
    distinct(),
    auditTime(300)
  )
})
```

How would I create a new observable using an existing observable and a function like this? The new observable should emit values with a shape of `{ counter, username, input }` with the latest values of their respective observables, defaulting to `null` when it hasn't received a value yet. (but possibly an optional default?)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/observable/combineLatestObject.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const mapObservableToObject = o$ => ({
  counter: o$.pipe(
    pluck('values', 'counter'),
    startWith(null)
  )
  username: o$.pipe(
    pluck('user', 'username'),
    map(sanitizeUsername),
    startWith(null)
  )
  input: unrelatedObservable$.pipe(
    pluck('target', 'value'),
    distinct(),
    auditTime(300),
    startWith(null)
  )
})

const { counter, username, input } = mapObservableToObject(obs$);
combineLatest(counter, username, input).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this custom operator, as far as I can tell it should do the trick for you, and it plays well with TypeScript's type inference:

```
  import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  /**
   * An equivalent of combineLatest, but using named arguments.
   */
  export const combineLatestToObject = <T>(
    source: { [P in keyof T]: Observable<T[P]> },
  ): Observable<{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] }> => {
    const keys = Object.keys(source);
    return combineLatest(keys.map(key => (source as any)[key])).pipe(
      map(values => {
        const result: { [key: string]: any } = {};
        for (const index in values) {
          result[keys[index]] = values[index];
        }
        return result;
      }),
    ) as any;
  };
```

As for a default value before anything is emitted, you can add `startWith(null)` or `publishBehavior(null)` depending on your requirements. Also be careful with subscribing to `o$` twice in your code - this is fine if `o$` is a multicast observable, but just a heads up.